# KL Divergence for two probability distributions in PyTorch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I have two probability distributions. How should I find the KL-divergence between them in PyTorch? The regular cross entropy only accepts integer labels.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, PyTorch has a method named [`kl_div`](http://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.kl_div) under `torch.nn.functional` to directly compute KL-devergence between tensors. Suppose you have tensor `a` and `b` of same shape. You can use the following code:

```
import torch.nn.functional as F
out = F.kl_div(a, b)
```

For more details, see the above method documentation.

Comment: Yeah, I had seen that function, but it was returning a negative value. I figured out what the problem was: I had to use `log` of input, and the actual value of target. Now, it works fine.

Comment: you can also write the kl-equation using pytorch's tensor method. It is easy.

Answer (score 19):

function `kl_div` is not the same as [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Basic_example)'s explanation.

I use the following:

```py
# this is the same example in wiki
P = torch.Tensor([0.36, 0.48, 0.16])
Q = torch.Tensor([0.333, 0.333, 0.333])

(P * (P / Q).log()).sum()
# tensor(0.0863), 10.2 µs ± 508

F.kl_div(Q.log(), P, None, None, 'sum')
# tensor(0.0863), 14.1 µs ± 408 ns
```

compare to `kl_div`, even faster

Comment: It gives the same answer, therefore there's no evidence it's not the same. Speed is a separate issue entirely.

Comment: In my test, the first way to compute kl div is faster :D

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky Its not the same as input is `Q.log()` which is pretty non-intuitive when taken out of context of machine learning.

Comment: @BlackJack21 Thanks for explaining what the OP meant. While slightly non-intuitive, keeping probabilities in log space is often useful for reasons of numerical precision. What's non-intuitive is that one input is in log space while the other is not. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky I agree with you, this design is confusing.

Answer (score 13):

If you have two probability distribution in form of [pytorch `distribution` object](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#torch.distributions.distribution.Distribution). Then you are better off using the function `torch.distributions.kl.kl_divergence(p, q)`. For documentation follow the [link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#module-torch.distributions.kl)

Comment: It gave me NotImplementedError:

Comment: Check for pytorch version. I think it should be >1.0

Comment: `torch.distributions.kl.kl_divergence` seems to need distributions to be registered with https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#torch.distributions.kl.register_kl

Comment: Registration is the correct method.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the normal distribution, then the following code will directly compare the two distributions themselves:

```
p = torch.distributions.normal.Normal(p_mu, p_std)
q = torch.distributions.normal.Normal(q_mu, q_std)
    
loss = torch.distributions.kl_divergence(p, q)
```

p and q are two tensor objects.

This code will work and won't give any NotImplementedError.

Answer (score 1):

If working with Torch distributions

```
mu = torch.Tensor([0] * 100)
sd = torch.Tensor([1] * 100)

p = torch.distributions.Normal(mu,sd)
q = torch.distributions.Normal(mu,sd)

out = torch.distributions.kl_divergence(p, q).mean()
out.tolist() == 0
True
```

Comment: This does not seem to be supported for all distributions defined.